# ERROR in Illegal State: external references changed in

Tags: angular, typescript

I faced with a problem when i make some changes in a template a have an
**ERROR in Illegal State: external references changed**

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "9.1.13",
"@angular/common": "9.1.13",
"@angular/compiler": "9.1.13",
"@angular/core": "9.1.13",
"@angular/forms": "9.1.13",
"@angular/platform-browser": "9.1.13",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.1.13",
"@angular/router": "9.1.13",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "5.5.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-common": "1.2.3",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "4.3.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "4.3.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "3.1.5",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "4.8.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "6.7.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "2.0.3",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "2.0.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "2.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "1.5.4",
"@progress/kendo-drawing": "1.9.3",
"@progress/kendo-theme-material": "3.16.0",
"@q9elements/ma": "1.0.4",
"@q9elements/ui-core": "3.1.1",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"first-input-delay": "^0.1.3",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"isomorphic-fetch": "3.0.0",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"ng-intercom": "^8.0.2",
"ng2-google-charts": "^3.4.0",
"ngx-image-cropper": "^1.4.1",
"ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
"ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.1.0",
"raven-js": "^3.26.3",
"rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.7",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

},

```
  "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.901.13",
"@angular/cli": "9.1.13",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "9.1.13",
"@angular/language-service": "9.1.13",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.8.2",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/lodash": "4.14.117",
"@types/node": "^12.20.10",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
"husky": "^1.3.1",
"jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~2.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
"node-sass": "^4.13.0",
"npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
"prettier": "^2.3.2",
"pretty-quick": "^3.1.1",
"protractor": "~5.4.1",
"ts-node": "~4.1.0",
"tslint": "~5.20.1",
"typescript": "3.8.3",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0"
```

}
This usually occurs after second change in a template. Please help me with it, it takes a lot of time, because i need to rebuild my project every time when this happen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have solved this issue. Main problem was that in my angular.json option "aot" = true but this option good when you use ivy. After set aot = false, problem was disappeared.